# RecyclerView + searchView

Tags: android, search, android-recyclerview

I've got problem with search option in my app. I'm using recyclerView and everything works fine ... everything except searchView. Entering query in search field changes nothing in ListView. Maybe you could help me ? I've got method replace in my adapter which looks like this :

```
 public void replace(List<Concert> concerts) {
        if (concerts != null) {
            concertList = concerts;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
```

then my fragment class looks like this :

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {


SearchView mSearchView;
RecyclerView mSearchRecyclerView;
Activity mActivity;
SearchAsyncTask mSearchAsyncTask;
Concert concert;
List<Concert> searchedList = new ArrayList<>();
ConcertAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search_layout, container, false);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) v.findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    mSearchView.setQueryHint("Kogo chcesz posłuchać?");
    mSearchRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.search_concerts_rv);
    adapter = new ConcertAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), new ArrayList<Concert>(), (MainActivity) mActivity);
    mSearchRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mSearchRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
    mSearchAsyncTask = new SearchAsyncTask(SearchFragment.this);
    futureConcerts();

    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            Log.d("Search", "SearchOnQueryTextSubmit: " + s);
            search(s);
            return true;

        }
    });

    return v;
}
public void futureConcerts() {
    mSearchAsyncTask.execute();
    getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().setClickable(false);
}
public void notifyAboutListCreation(List<Concert> res) {
    adapter.replace(res);

}
private boolean search(String search) {
    List<Concert> subList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Concert concert : searchedList) {
        if (concert.getTitle().toLowerCase().contains(search.toLowerCase())) {
            subList.add(concert);
            Log.d("added", concert.getTitle());
        }

        adapter.replace(subList);
    }

    return true;
}

}
```

You can write whatever you want but listView stays the same :/ Any idea why it doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

Because searchedList is empty. You are looking for Concerts in an empty list.